# Retrieving selections from Multiple-N number of Listboxes within a view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an editor template within my view which has a Model property called service types.  In short, there could N number of listboxes rendered on the page.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.ServiceTypes, new MultiSelectList(RunLog.Domain.Lists.GlobalList.PartsServiceTypes(), "ID", "Name"), new { style = "width: 200px; height: 80px;", id = "lstbox", name = "listbox" } )
```

The following Jquery .Load function renders the partial View.  In this dialog box there is a treeview with checkboxes, once they select/check items from the treeview and hit select, for instance they select 10 checkboxes, after hitting select 10 list vboxes will appear. There is a jquery .load which gets information from the action and renders the list boxes.

```
if (btnText == 'Select') {
                partTextArea = "";
                $("#parts :checkbox:checked").each(function () {

                    var v = $(this).val();
                    if (partTextArea.length > 0) {
                        partTextArea = partTextArea + "| ";

                    }
                    partTextArea = partTextArea + v;
                });

                $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
                $("#inputParts").load(serviceListPartsUrl, { ServiceEntryID: $("#ServiceEntryID").val(), Parts: partTextArea });

                $('body').css('cursor', 'auto');
            }
```

Now the problem is after every time this .load occurs, the previosuly selected servcietypes in the multiple listboxes are lost.  Any ideas?

Comment: it sounds like you are replacing all the listboxes every time you call load, are they all inside $('#inputParts')?

Comment: Yes, what @BassamMehanni says. A possible way ahead would be to arrange for each listbox to have a unique id and for these same ids to appear again in the re-served partial, then you can get jQuery/javascript to remember the listbox's values before `.load()` and reset them in the success handler.

Comment: sounds good, how should i close this question, since I now know the approach to follow.